# Is it possible to write a CLang plugin to warn on usage of RAW pointers?

Tags: c++, clang-plugin

Need to stop(or minimize) usage of raw C/C++ pointers in our source base (i.e. instead other options like references or smart pointers should be used).

Is it possible to write a CLang plugin to warn on use of Raw pointers (as local/global/member variables, as function return value, as function parameter) ? Or is this a definitely impossible thing ?

If it is possible, appreciate if you could provide some guidance/references.

Comment: Just a note. Don't demonize raw pointers. It still can be used when you need to use variable what can be `nullptr`, but without ownership change. See CppCoreGuidlines [1](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning) and [2](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r30-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics)

Comment: @P.Dmitry You could always use `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` instead ;-)

Comment: @eerorika What about functions like `write(ptr, size);`?

Comment: @eerorika, although not what I asked for, your idea seems a good idea. (I currently use my own class called UnOwnedPtr<T> for this).

Comment: @eerorika, this(my class) is some what similar to std::experimental::observer_ptr  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr

Comment: @aKumara I was mostly joking. Using observer_ptr or your own version it would be better. And using a bare pointer is fine too.